# How can I redirect the output to a file in C?

Tags: c, pipe

I have created a file but how do I redirect the output into a file instead of the terminal? I tried using the > operator but kept getting errors. Any help is appreciated.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
        FILE *fp;       //File handler

        char cmd[] = "sort -n"; //sort -n sorts stdin in numerical order
        char pmode[] = "w"; //write mode - we are to write to a pipe

        fp = popen(cmd,pmode);  //Open the pipe (run command cmd as a child process)

        fprintf(fp, "3\n"); //WRITE data to pipe
        fprintf(fp, "1\n");
        fprintf(fp, "5\n");
         fprintf(fp, "4\n");
        fprintf(fp, "2\n");

         pclose(fp);        

           return 0;
                 }
```

Comment: > is a shell operator, not a C operator. Go back to basics and figure out what's C and what's shell scripting.

Comment: Agree with @almo, sans the snarkiness.

Comment: A simple google search would have got the answer faster and with less effort than making a post here. I just don't understand some people.

Comment: Er...the mis-used `cmd > file` construct was a key part of this question. Yes, it's wrong, but it shouldn't just be removed without an explanation. Please restore it, and while you're at it, fix your spacing so that `}` lines up with `{`.

Comment: My comment was not intended to be snarky. I hoped it was a dispassionate statement of fact. Apologies if it came off that way.

Comment: @redFIVE That's not necessarily true; googling "redirect output c" seems to me to show mostly results that already assume readers understand the distinction between C-code and shell scripting, which, as Almo pointed out, is the fundamental problem here. In fact, one result even points to a page about the C shell, which would be extremely confusing if one didn't realize that the C shell is completely separate from the C language! (Well, except for being written in C and having a couple C-like idioms.)

Answer (score 1):

Redirection is useful if you C application already prints to the screen, either by design or because the application's author didn't originally envision writing to a file.

If you're truly interested in redirection, then don't worry about FILE pointers in your code and simply print to stdout. Then, when you run your application, you can redirect as much as you want using the | and > operators.

On the other hand, if you're really interested in your application being able to write to a file, then your application needs to do extra work to obtain a file path/name somehow, open the file, write to that file handle--not to stdout--and finally to close the file. Also you'll need to take more care to watch for errors and handle them gracefully.

If you go this route, you can simply run your application and not worry about redirection because your application deals with the file I/O.

Answer (score 0):

The > operator does not affect the execution of your program. It is used by the shell to redirect what was outputted to stdout by your program to a file.

The shell is what runs your program, it is not a part of it.